# Beamer - Greek - Change Language inside `\author`

Tags: beamer, pdftex, babel, greek, author

I am trying to use pdflatex (and not XeLaTeX) for a Greek presentation. Inside authors I want to use another language (Let's say another name in English to avoid titlepage's solution. Let's suppose it was another author that needed different encoding/language for his name even if my example is not this.)

My problem is that the "changed language" by using `\foreignlanguage` command
is still Greek and so isn't really changed.

Here is the code and the output:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\title{Περι λυκειακών κυμάτων \\ (Λάθη στη διδασκαλία και προσπάθεια υπέρβασης αυτών) }
\author{Θρασύβουλος μαχαίρας\\{\foreignlanguage{english} Video Editing:}
  %1st alternative
  %\\{\selectlanguage{english} Video Editing:}
  %second alternative
  %\\\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
  %Video Editing:
  %\end{otherlanguage}
  \\ Κωστής Λελεδάκης}
\begin{document}
\section{Εισαγωγη}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also tried the commented two ways (even `\selectlanguage` or `\begin{otherlanguage}{english}`) But then the code could not compiled due to
errors:

> Argument of \bbl@pop@lang has an extra }.  \par l.11 \ Κωστής Λελεδάκης}

and

> Use of \begin doesn't match its definition. \beamer@andstripped ... Video Editing:} \\begin { otherlanguage}{english} Vi... l.11 \ Κωστής Λελεδάκης}

respectively.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or my mistake? If it is my mistake, please give me the correct way (no titlepages please... Just inside `\author` command)

PS: I am going to chose the simpler solution if possible with no extra packages because I suppose my request is a basic operation that beamer has to
accomplish.

Comment: I know I could try English as a first language and change every setting after that, but this is not what I am looking for. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax should be `\foreignlanguage{english}{Video Editing:}`

Off-topic: maybe it would be better to define alternative short author and short title or at least give an alternative with `\texorpdf{}{}` in ordre to achieve useful pdf properties.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\title{Περι λυκειακών κυμάτων \\ (Λάθη στη διδασκαλία και προσπάθεια υπέρβασης αυτών) }
\author{Θρασύβουλος μαχαίρας\\\foreignlanguage{english}{Video Editing:}
  %1st alternative
  %\\{\selectlanguage{english} Video Editing:}
  %second alternative
  %\\\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
  %Video Editing:
  %\end{otherlanguage}
  \\ Κωστής Λελεδάκης}
\begin{document}
\section{Εισαγωγη}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @semcarter... Didn't imagine that `\foreignlanguage` asks for a second argument... even if I should.